# How to create application framework like Contracts split screen?

Tags: android, tablet

Many apple ipad apps use UISplitViewController to create a landscape view with a list and then a detail panel to the right.  The Android Contacts app in Android 3.0 on a tablet does the same thing. How can I create a layout that mimics this behaviour so that I can build my android tablet app around it?  I guess I would use ListView in a layout that has a View derived object to the right.

The contacts app is fairly "pretty" as far as Android apps go.  Does google supply a code example for this type of program?

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's called fragments. It's available on Android 3.0 and later. Here is an article on the android developers website on how they work: [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)